# autocomplete for multiple search categories

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jsf, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm developing a search engine type of application using JSF. Upon searching using a keyword, it return results. In order to refine the search, I have to provide multiple filter categories, each having an auto-complete textbox and checkboxes in it. Upon typing in the textbox, it has to show suggestions and upon selection, it has to check the corresponding checkbox.

I tried jquery UI multiselect plugin, but the headers remain the same for all categories. (If I specify header for Product Line GPL in jqueryui.multiselect.js it appears same for all criteria).

Is there any other way to change the header dynamically or any other component that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps should you intercept click events in order to force button text content...